# Maximum size of JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I created JSF page with 51 insert fields. When I tested the JSF page I get this error:

```
malformedXML: XML Parsing Error: unclosed CDATA section
Location: http://188.254.222.137:8080/DX-57/RMC-57/DatacenterProfile.jsf
Line Number 222, Column 52:
                    <script type="text/javascript">
---------------------------------------------------^
```

As far as I understand I have hit the maximum size of JSF page. How I can increase the size of the Mojarra buffer? I use version 2.1.10. What is the proper way to solve the problem?

Comment: The exception talks you about a malformed XML because you did not close a CDATA section and you talk about size limits? Why?

Comment: @SJuan76: this concerns autogenerated XML code of a JSF ajax response, not self-written code (although it's indeed self-written code which has indirectly caused the particular problem).

Comment: This is not the problem with size. Please add more details for the question to be answered

Comment: @Chris: the size is indeed not the problem, there's absolutely no means of something nonsensicial such as "maximum size", but the excessive size *has* changed the way how the problem exposes itself. Increasing the buffer size as requested by the OP wouldn't solve the root problem, but only change the exposed symptoms.

Answer (score 2):

Here at our company we are using JSF and over the top primefaces. We have big
.xhtml pages and such an issue doesn't seem to be related to page size. Seems like
you have missed some closing tag and the jsf page is complaining about malformed
XML. Recheck your self-written code. Try to figure out if you have missed something.
That might help.
BR,
Ben